# How can I dynamically create setup file based on unique identifier?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, inno-setup, outlook-addin

I have created an outlook Add-In and its working perfectly fine, but I would like to know how can I create a setup file for Add-in where Add-in has unique company details, so as there might be lots of company list, how can I compile setup file with Unique ID for every company, as it will be dynamic.

Is it possible to do? If yes how can I accomplish it? If not is there any alternative idea to accomplish it? Is it something possible with inno-setup? Is it possible to compile the exe file at runtime in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can build the setup passing values to the preprocessed script. There is the `/d` command line parameter of the command line [`preprocessor compiler`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_isppcc.htm). See e.g. this very simple script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
AppPublisher={#Publisher}
AppPublisherURL={#PublisherWeb}
```

This script you can build with the `ISCC.exe` command line tool passing the values to the expected variables e.g. this way:

```
iscc "/dPublisher=My Company" "/dPublisherWeb=www.example.com" "c:\Script.iss"
```

That will preprocess the script passing the values and build the output setup binary. If you'd like also to save the preprocessed scripts somewhere, you can put a line like this to the very end of your script:

```
#expr SaveToFile("c:\PreprocessedScript.iss")
```

That will store the script with the values filled by preprocessor.

Comment: P.S. I have used directives which are certainly not related to the company ID you need to be unique, but you can apply this technique to whatever directive you want, so it's upon you to refine this example into your real script.

Comment: is it also possible to use from php exec? i am not sure if i am right but it looks like it is supposed to work when u manually run the command. and how about if i want to get the values the set in the application when the application is installed for future use??? or registry could be a better option to store such?

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP. It's just a command line, so if you can execute command line tool from there, you can use this option. Another alternative would be to generate the script manually since it's just a text file, but I provided a general way. Your second question I don't get somehow. Do you mean how to read a value you set earlier by such command line build on the machine where you run the setup ? If so, then which directive do you use for your unique ID you've metnioned ? Anyway, this would be better to ask as a separate question...