# Using INI file to fill setup section values on inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, ini

I'm trying fill setup section values with {param} and {ini} like this:

```
VersionInfoProductName={param:NAME|My Product}
VersionInfoTextVersion={ini:ExpandConstant({src})\config.ini,setupValues,version|unknow}
```

But it is not working, in EXE properties is showing `{param:NAME|My Product}`
I also tried with GetIniString but same result.

How can I put ini values in Setup section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use any of the constants you have used, because both directives you're trying to fill need to be filled at compilation time. You will need to use the preprocessor function equivalent, because only the preprocessor can fill the directive values before the compilation starts.

The preprocessor's equivalent for reading from INI files is the [`ReadIni`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_readini.htm) function, which you can use the way which follows. Assuming you have a `config.ini` file stored in the same location as the script with this content:

```
[setupValues]
version=1.2.3.0
```

You can fill the value of the [`VersionInfoVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_versioninfoversion) directive this way. I have used this directive, since the value of the [`VersionInfoTextVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_versioninfotextversion) directive is displayed only on Windows 98 below systems and I believe you're not running such an old system to ever verify this:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoVersion={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "config.ini", "setupValues", "version", "")}
```

Note, that the `SourcePath` variable used in the above code is a [`predefined variable`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_predefinedvars.htm) that can be evaluated from preprocessor. The result you can then verify by checking the setup binary file properties and you will see e.g. this:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks, it worked! Now I have another problem. The setup section must have differents values, for differents languages. I tried use custom messages, but you already said this is not possible. Have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can only build each setup for different language separately. But there's a way how to build them by using command line parameters passed to the preprocessor compiler. For instance in [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20699259/960757) I've shown how to pass command line parameters to the preprocessor and that's pretty close to what you need.